# Custom post type post in custom menu

Tags: custom-post-types, menus

I created **Custom post type** named **Regular pages**. In that custom post type I created two pages **About us** and **Services**.

Is there any way to add that posts into my custom menu I created in Appearance->Menus?

Perfect for my if all posts created in **Regular pages** automatically appears in menu.

Can't add them like Custom link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Screen Options and you should see a "Regular Pages" checkbox that will add a box from which you can add "Regular Pages" to the menu.

Comment: You don't know, but you just save my life! Thank you a lot!